# Can I read Gradle properties in the 'settings.gradle.kts' file?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm using Gradle Kotlin DSL. I want to know whether it's possible to read Gradle properties in the `settings.gradle.kts` file?

I have `gradle.properties` file like this:

```kotlin
nexus_username=something
nexus_password=somepassword
```

I've tried the following but still it can't read the properties:

```kotlin
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            setUrl("https://some.repository/")
            credentials {
                val properties =
                    File(System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\.gradle", "gradle.properties").inputStream().use {
                        java.util.Properties().apply { load(it) }
                    }
                username = properties["nexus_username"].toString()
                password = properties["nexus_password"].toString()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your mean from reading the Gradle properties?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can access values set in `gradle.properties` in both `build.gradle.kts` and `settings.gradle.kts` using [delegate properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#delegated-properties) (Kotlin DSL only, because delegate properties is a Kotlin feature!).

gradle.properties

```
kotlin.code.style=official
# Your values here
testValue=coolStuff
```

build.gradle.kts

```
val testValue: String by project
```

settings.gradle.kts

```
val testValue: String by settings
```

Comment: This answer has saved me after an hour of searching

Answer (score 11):

You can access gradle parameters using [providers](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/ProviderFactory.html#gradleProperty-java.lang.String-) (since 6.2)

```
val usernameProvider = providers.gradleProperty("nexus_username")
val passwordProvider = providers.gradleProperty("nexus_password")

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            setUrl("https://some.repository/")
            credentials {
                username = usernameProvider.getOrNull()
                password = passwordProvider.getOrNull()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To work on Groovy, you need to replace the variable declaration with:

```
def usernameProvider = providers.gradleProperty("nexus_username")
def passwordProvider = providers.gradleProperty("nexus_password")
```

---

Based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72075210/11862732)

Comment: This appears to require at least Gradle 6.2.

Comment: @barfuin, yes you are right.
Here is a [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/ProviderFactory.html#gradleProperty-java.lang.String-) to the documentation where it says this

Answer (score 1):

You can access credentials from `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` using [built-in credentials management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:handling_credentials):

```
// build.gradle or settings.gradle
repositories {
    ...
    maven {
        name = "someRepositoryId"
        url = uri("https://some.repository/")
        credentials(PasswordCredentials)
    }
}
```

Credentials would be resolved by repository name and `Username/Password` [suffixes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#credentials_lookup_properties):

```
// ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
someRepositoryIdUsername=<user>
someRepositoryIdPassword=<password>
```