# Gradle Version Catalog (Published): How to dynamically set up repository

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm not that experienced with Gradle and are currently running into problems when trying to use the new version catalog feature.

**Goal**:

- Using a Gradle 7.4.2 version catalog, managed in a standalone GIT repository and published to private JFrog artifactory, in a second project.
- Every project member's artifactory credentials are already available in `$HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties` (auto-generated by JFrog) and are supposed to be re-used.

**Issue**:

1. according to the [current Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sec:importing-published-catalog), a published version catalog is supposed to be defined in `settings.gradle(.kts)` within any project that wants to use the catalog; 
   inserting that piece of code results in an error because Gradle has no repository definition available for artifact look-up
2. therefore, adding a repository definition:

```kotlin
// my settings.gradle.kts
rootProject.name = "catalog-consumer"

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    val catalogVersion = "0.1.0"
    val artifactoryUri = "..."
    val catalogGAV = "..."

    repositories{
        maven {

            url = uri("$artifactoryUri")
            credentials {
                // TODO: how to access user's local gradle.properties for credentials?
                username = "$artifactory_user"     // key as generated by JFrog
                password = "$artifactory_password" // key as generated by JFrog
            }
        }
    }

    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            from("$catalogGAV")
        }
    }
}
```

3. now, facing the problem that the user's `gradle.properties` does not seem to be loaded, yet - but hardcoding credentials is not viable :)

**Question**:
Is the only option to manually check for and load the user's `gradle.properties` file?

Originally, when reading the documentation, I assumed that the settings file would probably try to look up existing repository definitions from the project's `build.gradle.kts`, but that wasn't the case either. If I understand it correctly, the settings file is evaluated before everything else, isn't it?

Manually loading the user's config just seems odd to me, therefore, I wanted to ask whether or not I'm missing a mechanism or lifecycle hook that would take care of this. Also possible that I use the version catalog feature incorrectly :D

Any hints very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the docs here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:handling_credentials

#### Named repository credentials

If you named the repository and add `credentials(PasswordCredentials::class)`...

```kotlin
// ./settings.gradle.kts

dependencyResolutionManagement {
  repositories {
    maven {
      name = "mySecureRepository"
      credentials(PasswordCredentials::class)
      // url = uri(<<some repository url>>)
    }
  }
}
```

then Gradle will [automatically fetch the username/pass](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties) from the first found definition:

1. Using a command line argument

   ```sh
   ./gradlew build -PmySecureRepositoryUsername=my-username
   ```
2. environment variables prefixed with `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_` (this is useful for CI/CD)

   ```
   ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_mySecureRepositoryUsername=my-username
   ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_mySecureRepositoryPassword=my-password
   ```
3. `$GRADLE_USER_HOME/gradle.properties`

   ```
   mySecureRepositoryUsername=my-username
   mySecureRepositoryPassword=my-password
   ```
4. `gradle.properties` in the project root - obviously don't put credentials in your project!
5. `gradle.properties` in the Gradle installation directory

#### Manual providers

If you need to manually set the property names, then you can define your own providers.

```kotlin
// ./settings.gradle.kts

val artifactoryUser = providers.gradleProperty("artifactory_user")
val artifactoryPassword = providers.gradleProperty("artifactory_password")

dependencyResolutionManagement {
  repositories {
    maven {
      name = "mySecureRepository"
      credentials {
        username = artifactoryUser.get()
        password = artifactoryPassword.get()
      }
      // url = uri(<<some repository url>>)
    }
  }
}
```

Again, then Gradle will fetch these properties from either

- `$GRADLE_USER_HOME/gradle.properties`

  ```
  artifactory_user=my-username
  artifactory_password=my-password
  ```
- or environment variables

  ```
  ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_artifactory_user=myUsername
  ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_artifactory_password=my-password
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much! The **manual providers** option works for me. I already had a look into the PasswordCredentials class but it would have meant that every developer would have been forced to rename the generated credentials file. With the manual providers i can just access them as I would within a build file /thumbup -> [ProviderFactory](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/ProviderFactory.html)